# Moving from rational style modeling to NoSql/Cassandra style

Tags: database-design, cassandra, nosql

I am trying to change my rational modeling to Cassandra modeling , I need to model the following structure :
I have stores, promotions and prices .
price list include all items in a specific store with their prices.
promotion list include promotion details (e.g discount) and the items included in that promotion and the relevant consumer clubs (e.g vip etc')
stores id contain chain id, sub chain id, store id 
This is how the lists look like this 
items (per store):

```
<root>
  <ChainId>7290027600007</ChainId>
  <SubChainId>001</SubChainId>
  <StoreId>001</StoreId>
  <Items Count="2">
    <Item>
      <ItemCode>11210000094</ItemCode>
      <ItemPrice>12.80</ItemPrice>     
    </Item>
    <Item>
      <ItemCode>11210000216</ItemCode>
      <ItemPrice>29.40</ItemPrice>
    </Item>
    </Items>
</root>
```

this is how the items list look like 
promotion :

```
<root>
  <ChainId>7290027600007</ChainId>
  <SubChainId>001</SubChainId>
  <StoreId>001</StoreId>
  <BikoretNo>9</BikoretNo>
  <DllVerNo>8.0.0.0</DllVerNo>
  <Promotions Count="1381">
    <Promotion>
      <PromotionId>168144</PromotionId>
      <DiscountRate>10000</DiscountRate>
      <PromotionItems Count="3">
        <Item>
          <ItemCode>11210000094</ItemCode>
        </Item>
        <Item>
          <ItemCode>7290011078806</ItemCode>

        </Item>
        <Item>
          <ItemCode>7290011078807</ItemCode>
        </Item>
      </PromotionItems>
      <Clubs>
        <ClubId>0</ClubId>
        <ClubId>3</ClubId>
      </Clubs>
    <PromotionStartDate>2015-01-31</PromotionStartDate>
    <PromotionEndDate>2015-12-31</PromotionEndDate>
    </Promotion>
</Promotions>
</root>
```

a very frequent query can be:

> for a for a given list of items codes for a given store and a consumer
>   club then fetch all the relevant item prices and all the relevant
>   promotions

(i.e promotions that contain at least one item from the given list and the consumer club and current date between startDate and endDate)

so for each item I will get the price and optional relevant promotions (item can be included in several promotions or none, and a promotion includes at least one item)
**how can I model that ?
one option is to create for each separate tables and connecting table (rational style) :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS promos_with_items(
                               promotionId varchar,
                               promotion_item varchar,
                               PRIMARY KEY(promotion_item,promotionId)
) WITH comment='Promotions with items';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS promos(
                               chainid varchar,
                               subchainid varchar,
                               storeid varchar,
                               promotionId varchar,
                               start timestamp,
                               end timestamp,
                               discountRate double,
                               discountType int,
                               clubs set<int>

) WITH comment='Promotions';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item(
                chainid varchar,
                subchainid varchar,
                storeid varchar,
                itemid varchar,
                itemPrice double);
```

**another option more Cassandra style (but doesn't feel right ) is a single table :**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items_with_promos(
                               chainid varchar,
                               subchainid varchar,
                               storeid varchar,
                               itemid varchar,
                               itemPrice double
                               promotionId varchar,
                               start timestamp,
                               end timestamp,
                               discountRate double,
                               discountType int,
                               clubs set<int>                               
                               ;
```

**but in this case what happens if the item is included in several promotions or what if is not included in any promotion 
what should be the key / index ?** should it be chainid,subchainid,storeid,customer club,dates   ?